# What sense of password for Keystore file?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I created Keystore file but I notice I can use just ciphertext for accesses to My Wallet!

If some one get my Keystore file he can use just ciphertext?

What sense of password for Keystore file if I can use just ciphertext?

I don't get it.

Or password need only for more secure sign transactions, but password not protect KeyStore file if some one get this file?

Comment: When you say access your wallet you need to be clear. Can you spend your money or only see it? Public blockchains like bitcoin and ethereum are public: everyone can see everyone's wallet - they just don't know who a particular wallet (address) belongs to. But only the owner can spend the money.

Answer (score 0):

Password is used to protect your keystore file. Without password you can not get private key from the keystore file so you can not create transaction.